# powershell - Formatting InstallationDate

Tags: powershell, datetime-format, powershell-3.0

Hi i want to compare the different drives.
How can i format the InstallDate?

```
 @{"Label"=" InstallDate ";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.InstallDate) –as [date]}}, `
```

There is only space in Powershell

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 5} |
Sort-Object -Property Name | 
Select-Object Name, VolumeName, FileSystem, Status, Description, VolumeDirty,`
    @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
    @{"Label"=" InstallDate ";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.InstallDate) –as [date]}}, `
    @{"Label"=" LastErrorCode ";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.LastErrorCode) -as [int]}}, `
    @{"Label"="Access";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Access ) -as [float]}}, 
    @{"Label"="BlockSize";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.BlockSize /1GB) -as [float]}}, `
    @{"Label"="NumberOfBlocks";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.NumberOfBlocks /1GB) -as [float]}}, `
    @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_.installdate` has data? Anyway type `[date]` doesn't exist (Have you build a custom .NET type  accelerator?), it's [datetime].

Comment: Oh..  I think that's the point. InstallDate has no data *g ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a date you can use something like this:

```
"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
```